# Transplanting Fortitude Trappings to Other Skills

Tags: dresden-files, fate

`Presence`, `Conviction`, and `Endurance` all have a *Fortitude* trapping that indicates how many stress boxes the character has on the appropriate track, i.e. `Conviction` has `Mental Fortitude` that affects the `Mental Stress` track.

On `YW147` the rules discuss mortal stunts, and one of the ways to create one is *Adding New Trappings* to an existing skill, which can refer to a new trapping, or a transplanted trapping from another skill.

**If a character's concept would indicate that they have the ability to fend off stress, but not through the applicable skill, would it be appropriate to transfer that trapping to the other skill, and what would that do to the stress track?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to alter the skill affecting a stress track using a stunt according to general FATE rules. The original skill would lose its effect on the stress track length and the new skill would be used to determine it.

You end up "transplanting" the trapping to another skill with the stunt. Not creating a duplicate trapping in the said skill.

I don't know if DF mentions this in the book explicitly but it should be applicable without problems.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know if the original would lose the effects or not- I figured it would, but wasn't sure.  `YW147` doesn't explicitly say whether transplanting *moves* or *copies* said trapping, and that was what was confusing.  I now see where it says that limitations can also be applied, and that makes it even better, i.e. the same as with inhuman toughness, the altered stress track would only apply under certain circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

My inclination is to make it a minor Refresh power of some variety, allowing them to have an extra "reserve" stress level in a given track.  I think that allowing this workaround discourages the use of a given skill, and might easily be abused to build a concept.  The GM, of course, has the final say in what happens (or doesn't) so if you/they want that mechanic to apply then so be it, but it wouldn't be recommended if you ask me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer- I was asking about a specific rules interpretation rather than an answer to a situation, so this wouldn't really apply.

Comment: Then I would agree with the answer before mine in that it comes from the other skill instead, not in addition to the original.  However, I think the book is implying that while they give you all sorts of trappings for skills, they want to remind the GM/Players that the book is never the be-all-end-all, and if you want to add a trapping you couldn't find you should do so.